# TypeScript: higher order function throws away type information for passed in functions

Tags: typescript, higher-order-functions

With higher order functions, TypeScript appears to throw away type information about passed in functions. For example, the following does not raise an error:

```
function func (f) {
    return f(1, 1);
}

function concat (n: string, m: string) {
    return n + m;
}

func(concat)
```

Of course, if you add the same type information to the higher order function, then it will catch the error:

```
function func (f: (n: string, m: string) => string) {
    return f(1, 1);
}

function concat (n: string, m: string) {
    return n + m;
}

func(concat)
```

The error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

However, there are plenty of times where you might want to pass in a function with an arbitrary signature and have this signature respected when it is later called within the higher order function.

I have tried to achieve this using type parameters:

```
function func <F>(f: F) {
    return f(1, 1);
}

function concat (n: string, m: string) {
    return n + m;
}

func(concat);
```

However, this also raises an error:

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '{}' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: I'll need an actual use case to understand what you're really trying to do with this function. It looks like you should specify the signature like this: `function func <T>(f: (n: number, m: number) => T): T {`. Then any function you pass in must loosely match that signature.

Comment: The problem with your first example is that the compiler infers and implicit `any` type for the function `f` and `(f: any) => any` for the function `func`. You can disable this using the `noImplicitAny` compiler option. As far as passing in a function with arbitrary signature, I think you meant to say arbitrary return type. In that case, what @AJRichardson said.

Comment: Thanks. But I mean arbitrary return type and arbitrary argument types.

Comment: You can't have arbitrary argument types based on your example, because you pass the arguments `(1, 1)` to the function. So you need to have fixed argument types `(n: number, m: number)`. What is your actual use case?

Comment: Yes, so in that situation I would want the fact that f is called with integers to give rise to a typescript error if the signature of the passed in function doesn't match. That's why I want to be able to preserve the type information about the passed in function - so I can make sure that it is called validly inside the function to which it is passed as a "callback".

Comment: One use case would be writing better type declarations for a library like `redux`. For example, it would be good to be able to have strongly typed reducers that only accept `state` and `action` arguments matching particular interfaces. Then, you might need to combine these using `combineReducers`, but have the type signatures of the passed in reducers preserved when the "combined reducer" calls them.